# 301 redirect all pages but only one rule to other rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect subdomain.example.com to newsubdomain.example.com.
Both are working under the same redirect rules, but one of these rules is does not do what I need it to do. I need a 301 redirect under a new rule (using another URL structure).

Example: 
http://subdomain.example.com/c/138  to http://newsubdomain.example.com/138/

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c/([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?category\.php$ http://www.alarab.com/%1/ [L,R=301]
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second rule isn't relevant here, only the first one.

---

There are two ways to do a wholesale redirect. One would be your attempt with [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), but you must capture only the final path part *after* `/c`, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^c/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R,NC]
```

The second way would be with [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) from [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html)

```
Redirect /c http://www.example.com
```

Both ways capture the part after the prefix and slap it onto the target path.

---

Finally, unrelated, *never* test with [`R=301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)!

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot
the first solution is good, but 138 is not the only number, and i can't know what is the list of these numbers, so can we do it dynamiclly ?

Comment: If the number is always the same on the target URL, see modified answer.